# how to change constructor value JS

Tags: javascript

I want to change constructor base value like I have:

```
function G()
{
    this.speed=1;
}
```

and `var k=new G();` gives me `k.speed=1;`
now I want that every time I create new G , its speed was like 10;
I tried

```
G.changeSpeed=function(){this.speed=10;}
G.prototype.changeSpeed=function(){this.speed=10;}
```

second works on already initialised ones, but first doesn't work at all ( error ).

any way I can do it?

Comment: Second one works, right? What exactly you want?

Comment: I want to create first 100 G with speed of 1.
then another 100 with speed of 10.
the again others with different speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
function G(speed)
{
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

You can do:

```
var x = new G(1); // x.speed = 1;
var y = new G(2); // y.speed = 2;
```

Comment: well. thanks. I think this will do it :)